# x% get a binary answer right - how many of them by chance (chance=0.5)?

Tags: probability

I was thinking about how to reply to people who keep correcting people about the distinction between poisonous/toxic or venomous/toxic/poisonous. *(Never mind that I get this wrong even five seconds after just having read the respective definitions because I just don't care.)*

This got me to the following problem:

Let's assume there is a 50% chance to get the answer right merely by chance (so assuming a binary question).

If I find, for example, that 70% of a sample got it right, how do I know how many got it right by chance and how many actually know what they are talking about?

*I had intended to argue that the vast majority of people don't know the distinction between those terms anyway, so it does not matter how it's used wrong in an Internet forum *not for subject experts* because the readers don't know the difference anyway. To support my argument I wanted to show that even if it is used correctly a lot of times most of it is due to chance, and that I can prove mathematically that very few people know what each those words mean given a certain percentage of correct usages.*

Here are my thoughts:

$R$ — number of people who get it right because they actually *know*
$R_c$ — number of people who get it right by chance
$W_c$ — number of people who get it wrong by chance
$x$ — number of people who get it right in a sample

- The sum of all the above is 100%
- The number of people who get it right in a sample is the sum of those who get it right because they know and those who get it right by chance
- Given equal chances to get it right or wrong, the number of people who get it right by chance equals those who get it wrong by chance

$\begin{align}
    100\% &= R + R_c + W_c \\
    x\% &= R + R_c \\
    R_c &= W_c
\end{align}$

So I tried an example, 70% got it right — can I definitely conclude how many (or how few!) actually *know* and used the correct words deliberately?

$\begin{align}
    70\% &= R + R_c \\
    100\% &= 70\% + W_c \\
\end{align}$

Therefore $W_c = 30\%$, and it follows that $R_c = 30\%$

Which means that $100\% = R + 30\% + 30\%$, so $R = 40\%$.

For an observed $x = 80\%$ I get $R = 60\%$.
For an observed $x = 20\%$ I get $R = -60\%$ (okay, because lower limit is 50% due to chance).

Which means that under the above conditions (two words, equal chances to use them correctly by chance), if I see that 70% of the time those words are used correctly 40% of those times people knew how to used them and 30% of those times the correct usage was by chance?

That seems too high to me. After all, if I see the correct usage 50% of times it could all be explained by mere chance. So I might not just have made a mistake... or not?

$\begin{align}
    50\% &= R + R_c \\
    100\% &= 50\% + W_c \\
\end{align}$

Therefore $W_c = 50\%$, and it follows that $R_c = 50\%$

Which means that $100\% = R + 50\% + 50\%$, so $R = 0\%$.

Hmm. I think I might try to get a curve with *x* being the number of people who "know" and *y* being the number of correct usages I can observe later today.

---

**EDIT**

I have provided a specific method. I would just like to know if it is correct and if not what I overlooked. I am sure there are many much more complicated methods for much larger versions of this problem. But I want to develop MY OWN method for MY problem (such is learning), not just learn somebody else's solution. So my question is about MY solution, given here.

What, if anything, did I(!) do wrong? Or is it correct? (for *this* specific problem)

For example, let's assume I find out that the links given to me in comments lead to a different answer. Then I still don't know what I did wrong!

Comment: This is a standard problem in multiple-choice exam grading. The examiner wishes to estimate how many answered the question correctly because they _know_ the answer but the information available is only the number of correct and incorrect answers. See Problem 6 on Problem Set 4 and its Solutions on the [ECE 313 Fall 2009, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/fa2009/Problems.html) website for a detailed statement of the problem and a complete solution for the usual 5-choice case. You should be able to adapt the method easily to your 2-choice case.

Comment: @DilipSarwate So is my solution incorrect? This is too complicated for me. I looked at it and it and I really would prefer to just look at *my* simple problem.

Comment: TL; DNR. Your question and approach is too complicated for me.

Comment: **I got the answer!**: http://mymathforum.com/probability-statistics/71331-x-get-binary-answer-right-how-many-them-chance-chance-0-5-a.html

It says my model delivers *correct results* (within the valid range of values for x between 50% and 100%).

Comment: Your attitude in comments toward people who have attempted to help you is not in keeping with the requirement to [be nice](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). Your response to a helpful comment was unnecessarily confrontational, as was your response to an answer. Please modify your behavior on this site. [In addition, if you want better answers, you have to start by asking clearer questions. Both your questions have attracted heavy downvotes and you may risk triggering an automatic ban on asking questions.]

Answer (score 2):

> If I find, for example, that 70% of a sample got it right, how do I
>   know how many got it right by chance and how many actually know what
>   they are talking about?

Simple answer is: you don't. And here you provide a simple counterexample when your logic fails:

> For an observed $x = 20\%$ I get $R = -60\%$ (okay, because lower
>   limit is 50% due to chance).

You can have from $0$ to $100\%$ (nobody to everybody of your sample), what would it mean that "$-60\%$ people know the answer"?! This does not make any sense. With $50\%$ chance of guessing you can get no less than $50\%$ points on average. So if chance of guessing correctly is symmetric to chance of guessing incorrectly, than there $50\%$ is the upper boundary for both values. Following your logic, this makes the rest of answers correct or undefined. This shows that the problem is not that simple (e.g. the probability of guessing correctly can be other than simply proportional to probability of guessing incorrectly - this makes your simple approach not applicable since $R_c$ tells you nothing about $W_c$).

In real life some people know the answers, some don't know at all but guess, some make educated guesses that are more probable to be correct then by pure chance, some people are inclined to guess incorrectly for some kinds of questions (so are more likely to guess incorrectly), some do not attempt to guess at all because they consider it "not fair", there could be whole groups of people who share similar incorrect beliefs about some topics and so answer incorrectly etc. The bare fact that for yes/no kind of questions it is possible to have more than $50\%$ wrong answers (and, yes, it happens) makes your method not applicable.

In real life it is more complicated and so your method won't provide correct answer. As I mentioned in my comments, in this kind of cases Item Response Theory models are commonly used (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142276/how-to-judge-which-test-is-more-difficult/142279#142279) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140561/what-is-a-good-method-to-identify-outliers-in-exam-data/140609#140609)). In such models you use logistic regression with two or more parameters for (a) item difficulty and (b) student ability, since at least those two factors influence the final result. For such estimating such model you need multiple students answering multiple questions to have enough information for estimating those two parameters. If your test is easy, while you get many incorrect answers that tells you something about the students, if it is hard, while there are some who get $100\%$ correct scores it tells you something about those students, if you give your test to group of geniuses and no one of them can solve it correctly, it tells you something about your test. It is not just guessing-or-knowing problem.

Comment: My logic does not fail -- the lower limit is 50% for x! So the -60% is okay because it is *impossible*. [Here I got the answer that I didn't get on this forum](http://mymathforum.com/probability-statistics/71331-x-get-binary-answer-right-how-many-them-chance-chance-0-5-a.html). You are incorrect: *"You can have from 0 to 100% "* I CAN'T! 50% is the lower limit (given a large enough sample). **I said myself that -60% is IMPOSSIBLE.** Which is why that IMPOSSIBLE result is okay. Because it is *impossible*. See the link, I was told my result is CORRECT!

Comment: You say *"$R_c$ tells you nothing about $W_c$"*. I'm not sure how to interpret this. We have *by definition* 50% chance of being right, so I *know* that those two are equal (on average, large enough sample, etc.). I have *defined* the problem so that they are equal. Not sure what your "but in the real world" is about, it is a *model*, which as far as I know is pretty common in all fields of science? /s Thanks for the link to the IRT, I've looked at it and will keep it in mind. It wasn't what I had in mind for my question, which was only about my model which seems to work (see link above).

Comment: @MörreNoseshine Your assumption is that probability of guessing correctly is 50%. So the lowest possible result you can get is 50% of "correct" scores (nobody knew the answer, everybody guessed, 50% were lucky). If you "obtain" data that has less than 50% of correct answers, then it shows that your assumption is incorrect since the result is impossible given your assumptions. Also chances of guessing correctly and incorrectly have to sum to 100%, it cannot be 30% and 30%. Those are the laws of probability. Period.

Comment: @MörreNoseshine if you are not interested in hearing answers, do not ask questions. You are **rude** in the way you form your question and in your comments. I would also consider buying a book on basics of probability theory before re inventing things yourself. I really do not care if you call your assumption an "assumption" or "definition", what I say is that it does not stand following simple rules of logic and probability.